# How to decrypt, create, and mount LUKS encrypted zfs raidz pool at startup?

Tags: zfs, luks, raid-z

I have an Ubuntu-18.04 box running the OS off an SSD which I do NOT want to encrypt. I have 3 additional 2TB drives which I would like to use as encrypted (via LUKS) RAID-Z1 additional storage. I would like to use a different phassphrase for each disk, be prompted for each passphrase as boot time, and automatically create and mount the raidz pool on boot as well.

I have been following the following tutorial.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/encryptedZfs#ZFS_on_LUKS_Installation

The tutorial above describes encrypting both the boot disk as well as the additional storage drive. Since I am not trying to encrypt the boot disk I tried to parse out all things relevant to that and only perform the operations required to create the additional storage on the 3 2TB drives I am interested in.

I have had some success in that completing the following steps does seem to encrypt each drive, with their own passphrase, and I can turn them into a raidz pool. There are two points of failure I have been unable to resolve:

1. My system does not prompt me for the decription passphrase at boot time.
2. The raidz pool is not created or mounted at startup. Likely at least in part because of the former problem.

After the machine boots I am able to manually decrypt and then import the previously created pool no problem. Here are my setup setups so far.

```
$ sudo parted -a optimal /dev/sdb; sudo parted -a optimal /dev/sdc; sudo parted -a optimal /dev/sdd
# the above parted command opens a prompt to enter commands. The following were the commands given
# mklabel gpt
# unit MB
# mkpart vpool 1 -1
$ sudo apt install cryptsetup
$ sudo cryptsetup luksFormat -c aes-xts-plain64 -s 512 -h sha512 /dev/sdb1
$ sudo cryptsetup luksFormat -c aes-xts-plain64 -s 512 -h sha512 /dev/sdc1
$ sudo cryptsetup luksFormat -c aes-xts-plain64 -s 512 -h sha512 /dev/sdd1
$ sudo cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup /dev/sdb1 --header-backup-file /home/user_home/luks_header_backup_sdb1; sudo cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup /dev/sdc1 --header-backup-file /home/user_home/luks_header_backup_sdc1; sudo cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup /dev/sdd1 --header-backup-file /home/user_home/luks_header_backup_sdd1
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 vault1_crypt
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc1 vault2_crypt
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdd1 vault3_crypt
$ sudo fdisk -l
# The above command was to check the sector size. because there is an old drive in there we have to use 512 sector size. This means using ashift=9 instead of ashift=12 when doing zpool create
$ sudo zpool create -O mountpoint=none -o ashift=9 vault raidz1 /dev/mapper/vault1_crypt /dev/mapper/vault2_crypt /dev/mapper/vault3_crypt
$ sudo zfs set mountpoint=/vault vault
$ blkid # Copied value of each sdb1 sdc1 and sdd1 UUIDs
$ sudo vim /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/cryptroot
# Wrote as follows
# target=vault,source=UUID=<UUID-from-blkid-for-sdb1>,key=none
# target=vault,source=UUID=<UUID-from-blkid-for-sdc1>,key=none
# target=vault,source=UUID=<UUID-from-blkid-for-sdd1>,key=none
$ sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
$ sudo update-grub; sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```